# fullcalendar.io render events with PHP/MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement this calendar into my site using a "while" command with PHP.  I dont know JSON or AJAX so not sure thats an option for me.  i have this code right now but it renders a calendar FOR EACH EVENT and not 1 calendar with all events on it.  I understand why, because i'm looping the whole calendar code, but is there a way to just loop the events?

```
<div class="widget">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner"><h6>Calendar</h6></div>
    </div>
    <div id="calendar" class="well"></div>
</div>

<?
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tevents";        
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    // Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $calname = $row['Event_Title'];
        $caldate = $row['Start_Date'];
        $calnotes = $row['Event_Details'];
        $caltime = $row['Event_Time'];
?>      

<script>
//===== Calendar =====//    
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [
        {
            title: '<?=$calname?>',
            start: '<?=$caldate?>'
        },
    ]
);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: "is there a way to just loop the events?...yes, just move the location of the loop to where you want it. You already start a couple of `<?php` blocks inside your script tag (to get the title and start values from PHP). You just need to adapt that bit so that the whole PHP loop will produce an array of JS events. json_encode() might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a json for events.

```
$events = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $events[] = ['title' => $row['Event_Title'], 'start' => $row['Start_Date']];
}
```

And then, create the calendar with the `$events`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    editable: false,
                    events: <?= json_encode($events) ?>
                });
```